# java property hashmap reading

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

**Answer**
I just found what I was looking for:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/somePath/file.map");
properties.load(in);
in.close();
HashMap<String, String> propMap = new HashMap<String, String>((Map) properties);
```

This allowed me to get the opened property data back into the hashmap with out needing to know the property names.

**original question.**

I have the following code that writes out the results of a HashMap. I'm wondering the easiest way to open this property back up and pull the data back into a HashMap, the putAll was a nice way to get the data into the property and store the data. I don't see a getAll to retrieve it, and the HashMap Key/Value data was not known before the hashmap was created so can't just retrieve by property name. The data after it was created will be static, so I could physically open the file written based off the hashmap to get the property names, but would rather not have to do it that way. Thanks for any help.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.putAll(mapTabSets);
properties.store(new FileOutputStream("/somePath/file.map"),"Java properties);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although properties do not have a getAll function, they do have

```
propertynames()
stringPropertyNames()
```

both of which will deliver a collection of all keys of the property. You can then iterate over the collection and extract all values from the property via

```
properties.getProperty(String)
```

Comment: Thanks.. Both answers helped me a lot, but I used propertynames() to get the keys as a collection so check this, but both got one up on answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("/somePath/file.map"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not having a problem opening the property file, just was not sure how to get it back into my hashmap, but I figured it out and added a comment to my question.

Comment: One thing to note is properties is an implementation of Hashtable which technically is a Map (has key-value pairs).  Good luck.

Comment: That helped a lot. Thanks.. They seem to be handled a little different in getting the data, like in a for loop if I understand what I'm reading, but that did help me understand it better.

Answer (score -1):

```
    package com.mkyong.common;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class ClassName {

        private static HashMap<String, String> mymap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        public ClassName() throws IOException{
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(ClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ini.properties"));

            mymap.put("1", prop.getProperty("required.firstName"));
            mymap.put("2", prop.getProperty("required.lastName"));
            mymap.put("3", prop.getProperty("equired.address"));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            ClassName className = new ClassName();
            System.out.println("The Value of Key-1 ::" + mymap.get("1"));
        }
    }

Use the properties file:-
****************************
required.firstName=Nitesh
required.lastName=Rathore
required.address=DangeChowk
```